# Microsoft LUIS does not let me change my Assigned Endpoint Key

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to change my Assigned Endpoint Key on a LUIS app from the Starter key to a Pay As You Go key that I have created. I'm doing this in the 'Publish App' section of the LUIS dashboard. I can select the new key, and click Save, but this doesn't seem to do anything. The dialog disappears, but the Starter Key is still the Assigned Endpoint Key. I can do this as many times as I like, but it just doesn't save.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using luis in a European region. You should use https://eu.luis.ai instead of https://luis.ai

Comment: any documentation to back that claim?

Comment: This worked - I switched to eu.luis.ai and was able to change keys without a problem. Impressively bad UX from Microsoft to give no error message at all on luis.ai. Luckily it is easy to export/import your apps so migrating to eu.luis.ai wasn't a big job :)

Comment: Well, it is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/manage-keys#publishing-regions